# How to control which overlapping polygon is assigned using polygon to raster?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, polygon

I have multiple overlapping polygons that represent fire perimeters.   Each polygon has several attributes including year.   I'm turning this shapefile into a raster in ArcGIS 10.5 and I'd like for the most recent year to be on top.  Currently it seems to be placing them randomly.

Comment: Please take the [tour] that outlines our focused Q&A format.  It is not clear what you are asking here.  What is "the issue of representing overlapping polygons with a raster"?  Please [edit] your question to describe clearly what you are trying to do, and the problem you are encountering.  Which GIS software are you using?

Comment: Try this https://github.com/ecohealthalliance/fasterize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Polygon to Raster (Spatial Analyst)](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/polygon-to-raster.htm) tool has the `priority_field` option that would work in the case of overlapping polygons.

> This field is used to determine which feature should take preference
>   over another feature that falls over a cell. When it is used, the
>   feature with the largest positive priority is always selected for
>   conversion irrespective of the Cell assignment type chosen.

Comment: Thank you.   So in the case of Year,  where I want the most recent year on top,  I would set the priority field on a numeric 'Year' field.  

So the priority field always puts the highest value on top?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score -1):

if you are looking for the generated raster layer to have the value field = to the "year" attribute of the feature layer, so that where multiple polygons overlap the raster value is that of the most recent year, ArcGIS does not have any way of doing this, unfortunately (and quite surprising).